# android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton vs org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.3.1

Tags: android, android-annotations

Someone help me: 
why **FloatinActionButton** does not work with **androidannotations** genereted class?
This error is actual for **Android API 22 or later**

There is here a activity: 
[image]

There is a view: 
[image]

The question of efficiency: FloatingActionButton.
So it works:
[image]

And this is not working: 
[image]

It does not work: it means the application runs **(with no errors), but the button does not respond.**

Comment: Please ask me if you need the full project code :)
I'll post link to github project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `setContentView` in your `onCreate()` method **and** the layout resource in the `@EActivity` annotation. This will and up in overriding your `onCreate()` method and setting the content view again. So this way not the layout and FAB is added in the end, but another layout is inflated by AndroidAnnotations and set.

You should not set the content view manually if you are using AA. Also i suggest to use the annotations if you are using the library anyway. :) That means you can use `@Click` annotation to set up click events on your views and `@ViewById` to inject views into fields. But be sure to work with those injected fields in `@AfterViews` annotated methods and not in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android annotation than you have to write like this to get id

```
@ViewById
FloatingActionButton fab;
```

If you want to click on fab button than write simple

```
@click
void fab(){}
```

for more information  [check this](http://androidannotations.org/)